# Reprojection not working with raster even though properties say its in the correct projection

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

I have a raster file that keeps placing itself in the South Pacific Ocean, West of Peru. But it should be placing itself over Colorado. I have tried using the tool "Define Projection" in ArcGIS Pro and "Project Raster", but it still places itself in the ocean. I doubled checked the raster properties, and under Geographic Coordinate System it says NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_13N, but again it places itself in the ocean and not over Colorado.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Does this information help? It's from the original file I have before I re-projected it. It should cover the entirety of Colorado.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is in fact one of the most frequent issues in GIS SE.  The root problem is that a wrong coordinate reference has been assigned. Unfortunately, we don't know: Where you got the data, where it ought to be located, what the exact coordinate reference was, and the exact extent, what has been changed since the wrong location was specified, what the data now reports as extent.  Please [Edit] the question to fill in necessary details.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I uploaded a screenshot of the raster properties. Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: This data is ***not*** in UTM. It's in decimal degrees.

Comment: Thank you Vince. I did not take notice to that detail! How frustrating! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vince noted, the raster has the wrong CRS attached to it. Looking at the extents, one can guess that the values are in degrees and not in meters and they actually correspond to the extents of Colorado which is 37 to 41 N and 102 to 109W. The solution is to attach a geographic coordinate system to the raster such as WGS84 (or GRS1980) and then reproject to UTM. You can do that in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro using the Define Projection tool.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I defined the projection to GRS1980 and then projected the raster to NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_13N successfully.